# Chaining Flows / Process builders and governor limits

Tags: process-builder, governorlimits

We have one large process builder on the lead object which is critical for several business processes. The challenge we're facing is that multiple devs modifying the PB in the same sprint is making it difficult to track and merge changes successfully.

My idea is to break this process down into one core PB which invokes various child PBs. This decreases the likelihood of changes in one area impacting one another. Challenge is that we're tight on our governor limits.

Questions:

1. Last year I spoke with a technical rep from Salesforce and they said that PBs/Flows are ~100x more expensive on system resources as compared to Workflows. If I have a PB which calls other PBs, is that cost doubled each time I call a subflow? Or is it a one off cost to invoke some kind of 'Flow engine'?
2. As a result of my above idea, we'll have one master PB and many child PBs. Aside from writing 'Put it in code', do you have any better ideas? The master PB will still be fairly complex so I don't think this entirely solves the problem. My other thought is a before insert flow for anything that can be used to exclude bits.

I couldn't find anything from searching here, so apologies if this question has already been asked.
Cheers

Comment: Might want to add more clarity on what that PB does as David's answer will improve performance greatly if it's simply updating the same lead record again (order of execution, prevent recursion). If it's doing other things, then it might make sense to split out between before-save flow + after-save flow. Before would handle same record updates and after does anything that is targeting an update/create of a different object. I don't have any docs, but I noticed a large increase in performance from simply combining PBs as well (ex. went from 4 PBs on same object to 1).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm considering a before-save flow when possible. Mostly for exclusion rules.

A large amount of the work done requires the recordId so they would still be after save flows/PBs. Creating child objects, Sending information to endpoints (including record Id) etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider [record-triggered before-save flows now](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_concepts_trigger_record.htm&type=5):

> Perhaps you’re familiar with Process Builder and using a record-change
> process to make additional updates to each record that triggers the
> process. Before-save updates in flows accomplish that same goal, but
> much more quickly because each record doesn’t get saved to the
> database again.

The only current drawback is you can't test ISCHANGED / prior value, but when Spring 21 is released in mid-February, you can [reference prior value](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_fbuilder_prior_values_flow.htm&release=230&type=5):

> Now when a record is updated, you can access that record’s prior
> values in Salesforce Flow. The $Record__Prior global variable contains
> the record’s values immediately before the flow was run

Comment: So trigger.old? Wonderful. Thank you. It won't solve all of our problems as per my other comment but it will help.